# Part wildcard in hosts subdomain possible?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, hosts-file, wildcards

On our server we've got a lot of redirects for specific subdomains, which always end in the same:

```
127.0.0.1    abc-thesame.domain.com
127.0.0.1    def-thesame.domain.com
127.0.0.1    xyz-thesame.domain.com
etc.
```

Is there a way to make this a wildcard so that I don't have to set all of them? I tried

```
127.0.0.1    *-thesame.domain.com
```

but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a hosts file, however if you run DNSMASQ you can do this - apparently wth a config line in dnsmasq.conf like

> address=/.domain.tld/127.0.0.1

Unfortunately this is a wildard for (anything).domain.tld - which means it would catch anything for this domain name unless it was more specifically referenced.   (You may be able to get a version of dnsmasq which has a regex patch)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. A regex would indeed solve it, I'll look out for that. If not, we'll keep on using the hard coded variety in the meantime. Thanks!