# how to block subdomains using host file in windows

Tags: windows, hosts-file

I have seen that I can block access to web pages with the host file:

```
127.0.0.1   www.facebook.com
```

how can I block all subdomains? *.facebook.com

Comment: `hosts` can't do wildcards - see https://superuser.com/questions/1348932/part-wildcard-in-hosts-subdomain-possible

Comment: @Tetsujin ok exist any other way to do in windows???

Comment: or some tool other than a firewall / antivirus?

Comment: You could try Pi-hole if you own a Raspberry Pi

Comment: @Gantendo no, I only have the laptop that my son will use ... but since he is only 11 years old, I don't want him to be running that has to do with facebook domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add this list to the hosts file: https://pastebin.com/vfR30GmS
That is a list of 115 facebook.com subdomains. Remember to block facebook.com itself too.

Comment: ok but can you indicate where you got it from how did you get it? as this list may change ... in the not too distant future with **meta** implementation ...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent I got the list from https://github.com/JamieFarrelly/Popular-Site-Subdomains/blob/master/Facebook.com.txt and I added `127.0.0.1  ` in front of every line using Notepad++ (regex search and replace).

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent I found a longer one https://github.com/d43m0nhLInt3r/socialblocklists/blob/master/Facebook/facebookblocklist.txt note that 0.0.0.0 is the same as 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok thank you i am testing it

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 doesn't appear to support subdomains in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` but you can use a more capable DNS proxy like [FLOSS](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.en.html)/[GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) [Acrylic](https://mayakron.altervista.org/support/acrylic/Home.htm) to block DNS by pattern and regex as well.

1. Install and/or run Acrylic
2. Edit `AcrylicHosts.txt` via the UI
3. Set your IPv4 and IPv6 network adapter properties to `127.0.0.1`